# Writing html code dynamically to an aspx file

Tags: sql-server, html, io

I have HTML stored in a Microsoft SQL Server column, and I also have an blank `.aspx` file called `myreport.aspx`. My problem now is, when I retrieve the contents of the column from the database, I want to be able to write it to the empty `myreport.aspx` file and use `Response.Redirect()` to call the `myreport.aspx` and display it.

The contents of the column looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
   <h1>Welcome Aboard!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

And also replace the contents with a new one whenever the page is being called.

I need help, thank you in advance, seniors!

Comment: Why are you storing entire html documents in your database?  Why not just store the report data, possibly in a normalized table structure, and then populate a report page based on that?

Comment: What happened was, I used txt control express in a windows desktop environment and now I am porting the app to a web site.

Comment: You could use a HTTP handler (.ashx) to return the HTML content.  I'm not sure on your requirements of the page being called 'myreport.aspx'.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972953.aspx